# Is there a way to share resources of a machine by running a program on one machine, but display it on another?

Tags: hardware, ssh, ram

Is there a way to sort of "share" processing power between two machines? I already use x2x and ssh to communicate between the two, but the two but that works with two moniters aswell. Is there a way I could have them both connected, but if I click an app on one machine (lets say cpu1) it would open on the machine with the most available RAM, and if it opens on cpu2 the window itself would still be on cpu1?

Big ask, I know. If I haven't been clear enough then just ask.

More importantly, will anyone help me code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to run a X11 aplication on a remote machine and display the result on the local one. This is as simple as

```
ssh -Y user@remote gedit
```

Comment: Really that simple? wow! Is it quite fast?

Comment: It's that simple thanks to the client-server architecture of X11. When it comes to performance, it works great on a local network.

Comment: Just tried it. Ran Spotify from my desktop, displayed it on my laptop, and controlled the sound that came through my big speakers remotely! All that comes next is the final bit of what I said - to make the computer automatically start a program on a second machine if the resources are running low.